# Check child checkbox, if parent checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have nested list with check box on each `li` tag,

**My question is :**
if parent check box is checked then all its child check box should also be checked.

Example from [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/):  if i check "sub foods" Then all check box under sub foods i.e X,Y,Z should also be checked.
How to do this using jquery

```
 <div id="checboxlist">
  <ul> 
    <li id="taskrow_id1"><input type ="checkbox"> Sub food
        <ul> 
            <li id="taskrow_id4"><input type ="checkbox"> X</li>

            <li id="taskrow_id5"><input type ="checkbox">Y</li>
             <li id="taskrow_id6"><input type ="checkbox">Z</li>
         </ul>  
        </li>

    <li id="taskrow_id2"><input type ="checkbox">B</li>
    <li id="taskrow_id3"><input type ="checkbox">c</li>
 </ul>  
</div>
```

I tried  like this  but its doing nothing

```
$("#taskrow_id1").closest('ul').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: use .children or .find methods like $("#taskrow_id1").find('input').attr('checked', true);

Comment: Am very upset with the person  who did -ve vote, you are not writing comment simply doing -ve vote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use a combination of [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and [`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) to find the elements and adjust their `checked` properties:

```
$("#taskrow_id1").click(function(){
    var checkboxes = $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]");
    checkboxes.prop("checked", checkboxes.prop("checked"));
});
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/6/)

---

However, if you're going to be re-using this multiple times, give the elements a `class` instead and simply replace the `ID` selector in my jQuery with the `class` selector.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You could make this a lot simpler by giving the child checkboxes a class name (e.g. 'foo').

```
  $('#sub_food_check_box').click(function() {
        $('.foo').prop('checked', true);    
});
```

Comment: It will be a mess if there are a lot of parent groups.

Comment: @DanielCheng my project is complex, those parent are dynamicaly generated

Comment: @user2173803 if they are dynamically generated, could you not set the class attribute and use this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle is here

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5N6TL/12/)

At first , you can add some class to parent li tag, then jquery code:

```
<div id="checboxlist">
<ul> 
    <li class="someClass"><input type ="checkbox"> Sub food
        <ul> 
            <li><input type ="checkbox"> X</li>

            <li><input type ="checkbox">Y</li>
             <li><input type ="checkbox">Z</li>
         </ul>  
        </li>

    <li><input type ="checkbox">B</li>
    <li><input type ="checkbox">c</li>
 </ul>    


</div>



$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(".someClass").find("input").click(function(){
       $(".someClass").children().find("input").click();
    })
});
```